# Determine whether a series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3}{3^n}$ converges or diverges.

$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \left| \frac{\frac{(n+1)^3}{3^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^3}{3^n}} \right| = \left| \frac{(n+1)^3(3^n)}{(n^3)(3^{n+1})} \right| = \left| \frac{(n+1)^3}{3n^3} \right| $

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: In your opinion, what is the limit of the sequence $\left(\frac{(n+1)^3}{3n^3}\right)_{n=12,3,\ldots}$?

Comment: I'd say $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Yes. And therefore your series converges absolutely.

Comment: Oh, that's the answer already? OK thanks!